# Py - Subsetting a data frame based on contents of another data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, subset

Good evening,

in order to achieve what the title suggests, I tried the following code:

```
data = df[ (df.tipo_mov == 2) & (df.day == X_test.day) & (df.month == X_test.month) ]
```

But it report the following error: "  Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects ".

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you add some data samples? Maybe need change `df.day == X_test.day` to `df.day.isin(X_test.day)` and for 3. condition similar.

Comment: It doesn't work; basically, X_test is a subset of df